# include tex tables on the same page

Tags: include

I want to include a table from another tex file before another table but this pushes the to another page. Do you have any solution to sidestep the problem?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{margin= 1.5 cm}[geometry]

\begin{document}
\include{DS}

\begin{table}[!htpb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
% ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I tried scalebox to resize the second table but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include help?

Comment: It does help for sure. Thanks. And thanks for the edition of the question will try to learn from that as well.